# Dont Zip File (stay in createZipFileAtPath)

Tags: swift2, zip, ssziparchive

I Used [ZipArchive From Github](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive)

when i want upzip file by SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath , i can unzip file but after i want zip file by **SSZipArchive.createZipFileAtPath( : _ , withFilesAtPaths: _ )** waiting and not finished (cpu and memory is full used when run this code . but not finished)
my code is

```
SSZipArchive.createZipFileAtPath("(downloadpath)/App.zip", withFilesAtPaths: ["(test2path)"])
```

**swift 2.2
xcode 7.2.1
release version (v 1.5 and v1.4 tested)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSZipArchive in V1.5 is not working by swift (for create zip)
and work by Objective-C and just Create zip file (not append)
for append file can use [Objective-Zip](https://github.com/gianlucabertani/Objective-Zip)